# Whenever - Cron not working? Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, ruby-on-rails-4, permission-denied, whenever

'I have set up a cron with wehenever, but its not working. I tried to run the command manually and i get the error `/bin/bash: bin/rails: Permission denied`.

Here what the command of the cron looks like:

`/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/domain.net/main && bin/rails runner -e production '\''User.weekly_update'\'''`

I also tried to run this command as `root` but i got the same message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to make bin/rails executable:

```
chmod u+x bin/rails
```

This is, of course, assuming that bin/rails is owned by the crontab's user.

Answer (score 2):

I found that use of RVM can complicate this. A worthy alternative is to make your whenever job into a `rake` job instead of a `runner` job:

```
every 7.days do
  rake "user:weekly_update"
end
```

This does, of course, necessitate an extra bit of code in your lib/tasks directory:

```
namespace :user do
  task :weekly_update=> :environment do
    User.weekly_update
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and solved this as follows:

(iam work with rvm and my */bin/rails has already +rx privileges)

As you can see in [whenever-github](https://github.com/javan/whenever) you can change job_type within config/schedule.rb

```
job_type :runner,  "cd :path && /other-path/path-x/bin/rails runner -e :environment ':task' :output"
```