# Capistrano + Whenever gems - bin/rails: Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, capistrano3

I have a production environment configured that deploys and works as it should. Although I have encountered an ancillary problem that I can't figure out.

I am running the Whenever gem to execute a couple of cron jobs, the Whenever gem capistrano implementation has them deploying correctly and the scripts are executing. Although inside whenever.log I receive the following output:

```
/bin/bash: bin/rails: Permission denied
```

The script is using a runner to update from a RSS feed, this has worked without incident on a previous production deployment, although I deployed to the new server using Capistrano.

I searched around and found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463908/whenever-cron-not-working-permission-denied), although each time I deploy, I have to make bin/rails executable (due to datestamp deployment from Capistrano). Is there a way to make Capistrano make the file executable for me at deploy? Or is there some inherent security risk with making bin/rails executable?

Comment: I thought there was a ghost in the computer when I saw those files kept getting reverted to non-executable lol, had completely forgotten that was because of new deployments... But shouldn't this bin/ directory actually be in a shared_folder in the first place ? So we can chmod u+x once and for all ?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve my problem with the following (namespace including restart included for brevity):

```
namespace :deploy do

 desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Passenger restart mechanism
      execute :mkdir, '-p', "#{ release_path }/tmp"
      execute :touch, current_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :x_bin_rails do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      within release_path do
        execute :chmod, "u+x bin/rails"
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

So my solution was to make the bin/ folder a shared folder

```
#config/deploy.rb
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('bin')
```

Then on your next deploy, the bin/ folder will be symlinked to shared/bin

You just need to go to this directory once, move the executables from a previous distribution

```
cp /your_deploy_path/releases/PREV_RELEASE/bin/* /your_deploy_path/shared/bin
```

... and make sure you `chmod ug+x shared/bin/*`

Also in my case, I was running on an Amazon EC2-linux machine and for some reasons the bin files were generated with `ruby.exe` instead of just `ruby`. Make sure you check those files and remove the `.exe` extension if you're not running Windows.

EDIT - I am no longer sure about the previous answer as I have ran into bugs with rails + capistrano + whenever with that setup. The following did work however for Rails 5 + Capistrano > 3.6.1

1. Regenerate most up to date bins (you might have to do something like

   ```
   # bundle config --delete bin # Might have to do that
   rake rails:update:bin
   # git add bin # If your bin dir was in gitignore, remove it from there and commit it
   ```
2. remove `bin` from the linked dirs (so the opposite of my original solution) and add the extra line in `deploy.rb`

   ```
   set :bundle_binstubs, nil
   ```
3. Deploy. From here it would see the bin files were generated with appropriate -x permissions and correctly referenced the boot file

See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347033/rails-5-console-not-working-when-deploying-with-capistrano) for reference