# Rails 5 console not working when deploying with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-5

I amm using Rails 5, and I have half way deployed my app through Capistrano on server. due to specific need to loadschema, i ssh in and cd into the release/### directory and tried to run

rails --version # came out 5.0.3beta

bundle # works, everything installed

rails c # but this fail

running rails db:migrate also failed.

it seems to return rails generic help as like my directory isn't a rails directory.

i tried deleting bin folder, but still the same.
anyone know what could be wrong?

[image]

thank you

Comment: for those who down vote my question, please state your reason

Comment: May I ask why the down-votes?

Comment: exactly, i dont know neither... i encounter this problem too many times and non stack overflow question have solved my issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you're using capistrano to deploy your application. Have a look at this issue: https://github.com/capistrano/bundler/issues/45

The solution would be:

1. remove `bin` from the `linked_dirs`
2. add `set :bundle_binstubs, nil` to your `config/deploy.rb` to generate the binstubs

Answer (score 1):

To run the console try `rails console`. To run a migration try `rake db:migrate`

Comment: sorry ive a typo, ive used shortcut rails c and it failed and help is shown as rails does not exists in the directory