# How can I restore my Rails 5 binstubs?

Tags: bundle, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano3, bin, rvm-capistrano

I'm working in a **Rails 5** app on macOS Sierra and everything was going well until I was ready for production to a **Digital Ocean VPS**. I followed one of the most famous [Deploy Rails app tutorial](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04) using **Capistrano**, I after some bugs finally my app came to live running on production.

Now in my *local environment* when I run `rails server` or `rails console` **I got this warning** and I don't know how to fix it or whats going wrong with that.

```
Looks like your app's ./bin/rails is a stub that was generated by Bundler.

In Rails 5, your app's bin/ directory contains executables that are versioned
like any other source code, rather than stubs that are generated on demand.

Here's how to upgrade:

  bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
  rails app:update:bin          # Use the new Rails 5 executables
  git add bin                   # Add bin/ to source control

You may need to remove bin/ from your .gitignore as well.

When you install a gem whose executable you want to use in your app,
generate it and add it to source control:

  bundle binstubs some-gem-name
  git add bin/new-executable

=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

I have been searching whats this bug and how to fix it but I have no luck! And for reference it seems to be something with `Capistrano` but I have done what they said is the solution and it does not work or maybe I have not implement it in the right way:

> The solution would be:
>
> 1.- remove `bin` from the `linked_dirs` *(which was not my case)*
>
> 2.- add `set :bundle_binstubs, nil` to your `config/deploy.rb` to generate the binstubs

Some articles I found:

1. https://github.com/capistrano/rails/issues/171
2. https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/1675
3. [Rails 5 console not working when deploying with Capistrano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347033/rails-5-console-not-working-when-deploying-with-capistrano)
4. https://github.com/capistrano/bundler/issues/45

I really appreciate any type of help you could provide me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I know this comes a bit late, but I found that I could run `$ rails app:update` and it would restore/overwrite my binstubs... along with overwriting all the other configuration files you start out with. So be careful about that.

See the [Upgrading Ruby on Rails](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#the-update-task) guide for more on this task.