# Rails upgrade message "heres how to upgrade bundle config --delete bin rails app:update:bin" not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

Trying to upgrade to rails 5 in project. Currently I am doing everything in the Docker container but it seems like I keep getting this message.

```
 In Rails 5, your app's bin/ directory contains executables that are versioned
 like any other source code, rather than stubs that are generated on demand.

 Here's how to upgrade:

   bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
   rails app:update:bin          # Use the new Rails 5 executables
   git add bin                   # Add bin/ to source control

 You may need to remove bin/ from your .gitignore as well.

 When you install a gem whose executable you want to use in your app,
 generate it and add it to source control:

   bundle binstubs some-gem-name
   git add bin/new-executable
```

I tried the following at these posts:
[Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347033/rails-5-console-not-working-when-deploying-with-capistrano)
[Post2 (Jweslley's solution](https://github.com/capistrano/bundler/issues/45)

These posts state to just remove the bin and add a line in the `deploy.rb` file.

```
set :bundle_binstubs, nil
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
```

Added these two lines to the `deploy.rb` file in my local repo but it didn't seem to work and I still get the message.

Since I am doing everything in the Docker container via config files and Dockerfile, do I need to also alter the `deploy.rb` file in the Docker container as well? It seems like changing the `deploy.rb` on my local repo in vs code will only work if I am trying to run it locally.