# whenever gem with rails 4 application is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, whenever

I am trying to execute one task for development evironment every minute using whenever gem. I followed all the steps given in documentation for my rails 4 application.
This is my schedule.rb file

```
every 1.minute do
 runner "User.resend_confirmation_instructions_to_user", :environment => :development
end
```

an in my User model I have this code

```
def resend_confirmation_instructions_to_user    
  user = User.find_by_email("abcdef905@gmail.com")
  user.send_confirmation_instructions
end
```

and then according to documentation i updated my crontab. its not giving me an error but also i am not getting any output.
I simply followed this link http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-to-schedule-tasks-using-whenever/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have working email configuration in `development.rb` file.

Also after adding new task  restart the server and schedule the task again.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. nothing helped me. forget about emails , even if i write simple puts statement , nothing gets logged into my log file.

Comment: and what do you mean by schedule the task again? I am simply updating  crontab by simply runnig whenever --update-crontab

Comment: * * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/hemant/hemant/new_travelibro && bin/rails runner -e development '\''User.resend_confirmation_instructions_to_user'\'' >> /log/cron_log.log 2>&1'

Comment: "resend_confirmation_instructions_to_user" is defined as instance method, you should change it to class method as  "self.resend_confirmation_instructions_to_user"

Comment: check the log file cron_log, if it says "Permission denied" try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463908/whenever-cron-not-working-permission-denied

Comment: also schedule a rake task instead of runner in shcedule.rb file, it's much simpler